# Vue multiple select

Tags: select, vue.js

I would like to have multiple selections without multiple.vue librabry. I want to write it by my own. I have data like this in js:

```
data: 
   roles : [here data]
   form.roles: []
```

And my html with Vue:

```
  <select class="form-control required-select2" v-model="form.roles" id="roles" required>
       <option v-for="role in roles" v-bind:value="role.id" v-bind:selected="form.roles.indexOf(role.id) > -1">
                                        {{ role.display_name }}
       </option>
  </select>
```

How can I have in form.roles more than one role.id? I have to write maybe a method for this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do something like https://codepen.io/ittus/pen/vjdLvb

You need to add `multiselect` options to your `select`

```
<template>
<select class="form-control required-select2" v-model="form.roles" id="roles" multiple required>
    <option v-for="role in roles" v-bind:value="role.id" v-bind:selected="form.roles.indexOf(role.id) > -1">
                                    {{ role.display_name }}
   </option>
</select>
<div>Selected: {{ form.roles }}</div>
```

Comment: I want sth like this: https://vue-multiselect.js.org/ And I have a great look now, butI cannot pass few data ( here roleIds ) to my model

Comment: Where do you pass `roleIds`? Do you mean `form.roles`?

Comment: Yes - in form.roles i have roleIds

Comment: Did you check the demo at `https://codepen.io/ittus/pen/vjdLvb`? `form.roles` is an array?

Comment: form: {
                    memberId: this.member.id,
                    firstname: this.member.user.firstname,
                    lastname: this.member.user.lastname,
                    email: this.member.user.email,
                    roles: Object.values(this.member.actual_roles),
                },

Comment: Yes it is an array

Comment: I cheked this fiddle but I need to have like this: https://jsfiddle.net/02rafh8p/ and I wonder or I can change my code to do this?

Comment: I will be gratefull for a help